# Access Static resource stylesheet from Zip file in lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, stylesheets

When trying to access stylesheet  in lightning component it's showing error message

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS90,'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css'}"/>
```

> Failed to save AccountComp.cmp: unexpected token: ',' at column 18 of
>   expression:
>   $Resource.SLDS90,'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css'):
>   Source

Comment: I think you're missing the beginning of your formula. Shouldn't it start with {!URLFOR( ?

Comment: if i add urlfor its again give errorr...... No function found for key: URLFOR: Source

Comment: On a side note, You dont need to import SLDS CSS if you are using it components in lightning mode.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about visualforce. I think you have an unnecessary  ) at the end though.

Comment: Kasper its showing error after remove ")" by mistaken i added

Comment: You missed `/` before assets '<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS90,'/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css'}"/>'

Comment: @Reshma still error is remain same no change :(

Comment: I got the mistake that in my app use  extends="force:slds" now its worked... no need to use of ltng:require

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. I think you, like me, may still be used to the visualforce way of doing this :). The differences can be subtle at times.

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS90 + 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css'}"/>
```

Comment: I got the mistake that in my app use extends="force:slds" now its worked... no need to use of ltng:require